# android-support-v4 remove unused classes

Tags: java, android, proguard

Bacially, I am trying to shrink my application's .apk down to the smallest size possible.  I currently have android-support-v4 jar file imported.  My question is this: how do I remove unused classes from this jar file?

Not finding any information after quite a bit of searches.  If ProGuard is the solution, text to include in my proguard-project.txt file would be appreciated.

Comment: if you no required android-support-v4 then just remove from your libs and remove unusable class from android-support-v4 is not right way to reduce you app size.

Comment: I do use some classes for the app drawer.  If it's as simple as removing unused classes and repackaging then I'll do that.

Comment: I think you have to download android-support-v4 with source code from here : http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r6 and modify as per your requirement and make jar from modified source and add to your project this custom modified jar instead of default one.

Comment: did you use a ProGuard? http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: My understanding is that it doesn't effect lib jar files.  Am I missing something or can I use proguard for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard indeed shrinks the size of applications. It treats application code (src/...) and library code (libs/..., library projects) the same, so you don't need to change the structure of your project. It is especially useful if you are using small parts of large libraries, since it removes the unused parts.

The [Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) explains how you can enable ProGuard for release builds. If your application doesn't perform any reflection, the default configuration (with an empty proguard-project.txt) should be sufficient.