# Android support v4 lib - need to exclude some unused modules

Tags: android

I am using Android v4 library. There are some unused modules such as accessibility that I would like to remove from the dependency. I saw this link which says I can use ProGuard to do that, but I would like to know if there is something I can add to the gradle to explicitly set the removal.

[android-support-v4 remove unused classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709879/android-support-v4-remove-unused-classes)

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard does it by itself by default, but you may also "fix" your dependency using more specific lib instead of whole v4 package. [take a look on options](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html), maybe just one or two options will be sufficient for you

Comment: Thanks, I had checked that link but I could not figure out the right name to use for the module while mentioning the exclude. So it did not seem to work. That is where I am stuck, not having the right names to use to write the exclusions.

Comment: by default ProGuard is including all dependecies, if you want to exclude some package from ProGuard "touching" you may use `-keep class android.support.v4.view.accessibility.** { *; }`. This package will be NOT obfuscated and stay like it is (even if it is a part of larger lib with more packages inside)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.